# Making a text area that can be printed to from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextarea

I'm trying to use my program's output text area UI element to print progress and updates for my program rather than using the console output inside of Eclipse. Is a way I could say:

```
System.out.println(string);
```

but instead of printing to the console, print to my own text area on the UI. My code looks a little something like this (I've removed my other panel elements to focus more on this):

This is my `MainPanel` class, where I make the element I want to print to:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    private JTextArea consoleOutput;
    private JButton submitButton;       

    public MainPanel(){

        setLayout(null);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14);

        consoleOutput = new JTextArea();
        consoleOutput.setBounds(199, 122, 375 , 210);
        consoleOutput.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 4, 0, 0)));
        consoleOutput.setEditable(false);
        consoleOutput.setFont(f1);

        submitButton = new JButton("Get Cards");
        submitButton.setBounds(35, 285, 107, 49);
        submitButton.setFont(f2);

        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String username = "HenryJeff";
            String password = "Password";
            Cards cards = new Cards();
            cards.openTabs(username,password);
            }
        });
        add(consoleOutput);
        add(submitButton);
        }   
}
```

This is my `Cards` class:

```
public class Cards{

    public void openTabs(String username, String password){
         System.out.println(username + ", " + password);
    }
```

How can I replace the `System.out.println();` to print to my text area? I've tried making my `Cards` class extend my `JPanel` and have the console text area be made and created in there, and then adding a write to method that writes to the text area but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you want to display this user name and password in textarea?

Comment: yes, I want to print the username and password into the text area @Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainPanel` class

```
cards.openTabs(username,password,this);
```

and specify your `consoleOutput` as non `private` some default.

Change your `Cards` class

```
public class Cards{

public void openTabs(String username, String password, MainPanel panel){
panel.consoleOutput.setText(username + ", " + password);
//now both user name and password will be displayed in text area of MainPanel class.
}
```

Comment: `consoleOutput` is `private`.

Comment: Sorry I didn' see that. @Titus

Comment: Im running into the problem of the openTabs method saying that it wants a actionListener instead of this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, by creating a bridge between the `Document` of a `JTextArea` and a `Writer`:

```
public class PlainDocumentWriter extends PlainDocument implements Writer {
    public Writer append(char c) {
        // Note: is thread-safe. can share between threads.
        insertString(getLength(), Char.toString(c), new SimpleAttributeSet());
    }

    public Writer append(CharSequence csq) {
        insertString(getLength(), csq.toString(), new SimpleAttributeSet());
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Then:

```
PlainDocumentWriter w = new PlainDocumentWriter();
consoleOutput = new JTextArea(w);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(w);
```

And then:

```
pw.println(username + ", " + password);
```

Now, anything you write to the `PrintWriter` will show up in the text area.